# Tengo un error con la plataforma zeit.co al subir mi proyecto

Tags: nodejs

Cuando intento subir el proyecto me arroja esta alerta

```
PS C:\Users\Cristian\Desktop\website-node> now
> WARN! Your project is missing a now.json file with a `version` property. 
More: https://zeit.co/docs/version-config
> Deploying ~\Desktop\website-node under
```

Alguien a intentado subir un proyecto a esta pagina, el formato es en Node.js

Comment: Ahí el error dice que te falta un archivo .json  lo tienes? Ya revisaste la guía que ahí menciona?

Comment: Estimado,
Ya incorpore el archivo now.json y dentro de el puse { "version": 2 } ya no me arroja el WARN pero aun así no funciona.